# 'as has' or 'as does'

Tags: verb-forms, as

From [an article](http://www.foreignpolicy.com/articles/2014/03/11/sorry_putin_isnt_crazy) in Foreign Policy:

> The Soviet Union is no more, but the entity created specifically to
>   counter its military might thrives, as **has** the Pentagon's budget,
>   which increased relentlessly until 2011, topping $700 billion.

I wonder if the use of 'as has' here is grammatical. Shouldn't it be 'as does', that is, 'as the Pentagon's budget does thrive':

> The Soviet Union is no more, but the entity created specifically to
>   counter its military might thrives, as **does** the Pentagon's budget,
>   which increased relentlessly until 2011, topping $700 billion.

After all, the verb phrase used for comparison contains the verb 'thrives', not 'has been thriving'.

Comment: **as has (thrived)** It is the present perfect. I don't see any need to change it to the present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are two sentences combined into one:

> The Soviet Union is no more, but the entity created specifically to counter its military might thrives.

This is talking about the *present*. Said "entity created specifically to counter its military might" is still thriving at that point.

> The Pentagon's budget increased relentlessly until 2011, topping $700 billion.

This talks about the *past*. The Pentagon's budget increased *before* this point. It does not, however, tell us if the Pentagon's budget is *still* thriving, so we can't use the present form "does" here. We could use "did":

> The Soviet Union is no more, but the entity created specifically to counter its military might thrives.
>
> As **did** the Pentagon's budget, which increased relentlessly until 2011, topping $700 billion.

The "As" here simply refers back to "thrives" and indicates, as above, that "the Pentagon's budget" *thrived* just like "the entity created …".

> The Soviet Union is no more, but the entity created specifically to counter its military might thrives *as* **did** the Pentagon's budget, which increased relentlessly until 2011, topping $700 billion.

The choice between "has" and "did" here is mostly at the author's discretion. Personally, I would pick "has" instead of "did" because "did" implies the budget increased completely on its own, but as I said, both would be grammatically correct.

Comment: Oh, I can see now! Thanks, FEichinger! 'Has' relates to 'increased', not to 'thrives'. I just thought that was an elliptical construction. What if we write it thus: 
"The Soviet Union is no more, but the entity created specifically to counter its military might thrives, as *does* the Pentagon's budget, which *has* increased relentlessly until 2011, topping $700 billion." 
- would that be OK, I wonder. (the budget thrives now, and it has increased prior to 2011)

Comment: @CopperKettle That would be grammatically correct, but its meaning is different. It would imply that the Pentagon's budget *still* thrives - that is not given in the original quote. The original quote only refers to the past development of the Pentagon's budget, not the present.

Comment: Yes, I can see that the meaning is changed in my edition of the sentence. It's just that the original sentence seemed a bit awkward, hence interesting to analyse.

Comment: @CopperKettle: no, it relates to thrives.  See my answer below.  Also, I'm not quite comfortable with your reconstruction of the sentence.  "I have walked my dog every day until I broke my leg" is incorrect, for example; it should be "I walked my dog every day until..."  The reason is that "have walked" means that the walking is true from some point in the past up to now.  "I have walked my dog every day since he was a puppy" is correct, for example.  I put a fuller explanation below that might help clarify the tense usage in your original sentence a bit.

Comment: Yes, I've re-read the answers and see that it does relate to 'thrive': *has thrived*. It's just that SE doesn't allow editing comments after 5 mins.

Comment: LOL Yes, that is frustrating sometimes.

Comment: @FEichinger My opinion is that "as has the Pentagon's budget" is saying precisely that the budget still thrives. The "which" clause is attempting to back up the assertion. One could respond to this sentence by saying that the fact that the budget was increasing as of 2011 doesn't fully back up the assertion that it is thriving now. I submit that "the Pentagon's budget has thrived" makes that assertion unequivocally.

Comment: @BobRodes That might be the intention of the sentence, but it's certainly not what it actually says. That might be a mistake slipped in editing, but as it is written it does not convey that meaning.

Comment: So the Pentagon's budget increased until 2011 (it was clearly thriving then) and after that *has thrived* for some more time but with no clear indication whether this *thriving* continues at the moment the reader peruses the article?

Comment: @FEichinger Your certainty that it isn't so notwithstanding, I stand by my statement that it IS what it actually says. We'll have to agree to disagree, I'm afraid. That's my position, anyway. See two comments previous to this one for an example backing up my position.  Copperkettle, as my statement says, the use of tense here specifically is saying that the thriving does indeed continue up to the present moment. What is confusing is that the "which" clause implies that it is saying that it continued up to 2011 and remains silent as to whether it continues to this day.

Answer (score 2):

Another look that could be helpful is this:

> The entity created specifically to counter its military might thrives.
>   The Pentagon's budget has also thrived.
>   It increased relentlessly until 2011, topping $700 billion.

The third sentence is intended to back up the second (it doesn't fully, because it doesn't say that the budget thrived after 2011).  As you can see, there is a different tense in each sentence, and each sentence makes sense by itself.  Each sentence also expands on the previous one, so it makes sense to combine them.  The "as has" and the "which" allow the writer to combine all the ideas into one sentence.